# +m IRC mode for supergroups

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm looking for this kind of functionality:

> A moderated channel only allows the ops (@) and voices (+) to send
>   messages to the channel. All other messages will be blocked.

In other words, as administrator, I need ability to temporary allow/deny users to send any messages to my supergroup. It can be useful if I want my conversation to start at specific moment, or just to prevent accidental conversations when it's not required.

As a workaround for written above, now I can only remove the supergroup completely and add another one. Am I right here?

Also, if there is no such functionality described above, is there any kind of API to create a group and convert it to supergroup? I can do it manually from my client. But I wonder if bot can do that?

Comment: Interesting concept. As far as i now you cannot create groups via the bots.

Comment: So basically you want to enable/ disable incomming messages to your group at given times? You might try requesting this feature directly from Telegram Devs. This kind of feature might just be useful beyond your current scenario and to telegram in general. You could drop the suggestion via Twitter, I dont know of any other channel that receives suggestions for Telegram API